# how to Save image in sever folder

Tags: php, android, image, server

This is my php code for image upload.with some text.This script is used in an android app code. 
Image id ,Image url and text save in database correctly but image not saved in server folder. Why is happen?

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        $image = $_FILES['image'];
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];

        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        $sql ="SELECT id FROM uploadfinding ORDER BY id ASC";

        $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        $id = 0;

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                $id = $row['id'];
        }

        $path = "uploads/$id.png";

        $actualpath = "My_url/$path";
    // query for db 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO uploadfinding (image,fullname) VALUES ('$actualpath','$fullname')";

        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){

             file_put_contents($actualpath,base64_decode($image));
            echo "Successfully Uploaded";
            }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: to upload file you have to use move_uploaded_file() function

Comment: I have already use this but nothing happen

Comment: i can't see move_uploaded_file in your code

Comment: make sure you have set 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'

Comment: please show us your code from     FORM     tag

Comment: if you are talking about file_put_contents then it is used to Write a string to a file. check here -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: i told u that i have already use this function but nothing happen..

Comment: @Insomania plz see the code carefully..

Comment: Start by checking the file upload for errors [See the manual, its a very useful resource](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) specifically `$_FILES['image']['error']`

Comment: @AdityaBhatt where is the html???

Comment: try `print_r($_FILES)` to make sure file is uploading

Comment: There are _far too many_ issues with this script, it would take a training course to solve them all. SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: file_put_contents($actualpath,base64_decode($image));

Comment: the main problem is in above line

Comment: Thank U contributing.. but Plz see the code carefully before post anyone.

Comment: Problem had Solve by myself.. Problem was actual path variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is the working code for this question

```
<?php

     header("content-type:application/json");
    require_once('dbConnect.php');
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

     if(isset($_FILES['image'])){

      $errors= array();

      $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
      $location = $_POST['location'];

      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      $date=date('Y-m-dH:i:s');
     $path="folder_name/".$date.$file_name;
     $actualpath = "http:myUrl/uploadfinding/$path";
      if(empty($errors)==true){
           move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$path);
          $sql = "INSERT INTO uploadfinding (image,fullname,location,) VALUES ('$actualpath','$fullname','$location',)";
          if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){

             echo "message";
          }
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }


   }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added **'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'**, for example:

```
<form method="post" name="abc" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: file_put_contents($actualpath,base64_decode($image));

Comment: did you check permissions of the folder?